# file permissions in Unix

Tags: unix, shell, permissions

I am working on Solaris Unix.  I have a file with permissions:

```
-rw-r----x+
```

What does the `+` at the end mean?

Comment: that says you have extended ACLs on the file. check setfacl, getfacl to find out more

Comment: json, you should consider accepting answers to your other questions if there was one posted that worked for you. This lets others that view your questions quickly see if there was a solution.

Answer (score 3):

From `man ls`:

> If the file or directory has extended
>   attributes, the permissions field
>   printed by the -l option is followed
>   by a '@' character.  Otherwise, if the
>   file or directory has extended
>   security information (such as an
>   access control list), the permissions
>   field printed by the -l option is
>   followed by a '+' character.